# How to parse content of URL from http://www.cda.pl/video/videoId and will fetch video URL

Tags: java, android, video

I need to play video from  http://www.cda.pl which give Url from webservice response,like http://www.cda.pl/video/videoId but my problem is How to find video Url from this link ? Cda is third party server like youTube but not provide any API or Library so please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many days RND I have Found Solution,  CDA.PL is Third party server Which  not provide any api and also its video url is expire around one Day so we can't use video URL Directly but every time get from http://www.cda.pl/video/videoId using Webview as following way and play it video URL in Player.

```
     public void getVideoPath(String path) {
        if (progressDialog == null) {
                // in standard case YourActivity.this
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                progressDialog.show();
            }
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
            webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
            webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
            webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            webView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "HTMLOUT");
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {


                //If you will not use this method url links are opeen in new brower not in webview
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }

                //Show loader on url load
                public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {

                }

                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    try {
                        webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.processHTML('<head>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</head>');");
                    } catch (Exception exception) {
                        exception.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            });
            webView.loadUrl(path);

        }

        class MyJavaScriptInterface {
            @JavascriptInterface
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            public void processHTML(String html) {

                int start = html.indexOf("class=\"player-video\" src=\"");
                int end = html.indexOf("\" preload=\"metadata\"");
                String finalUrl = html.substring((start + 26), (end));
                playUrl(finalUrl);
            }

        }
try it.
```